# Running VM from external SSD drive

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I am using VMware Workstation 14 Pro, and I'm trying to run a virtual machine that I've downloaded from Microsoft and saved to an external USB solid-state drive. But when I attempt to open that VM (by selecting File|Open and navigating to the path on that drive), I get an Import dialog.

[image: Import Dialog Box]

I don't want to import the VM. I already have a bunch of VMs running from my hard drive. I just want to run the VM from its current location.

In years past, I always ran VMs from a USB drive using VMWare Player. I realize it could hit performance problems but that's what I want to do. I really don't understand why this is a problem with VMWare Workstation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the downloaded VM is contained in an OVF file and needs to be imported.

https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-DDCBE9C0-0EC9-4D09-8042-18436DA62F7A.html

Alternately, because an OVF file is just a compressed file containing all of the VM elements (configuration files, virtual hard disk, etc.) you can simply uncompress the OVF file with a tool like 7-Zip and then open it directly in VMware Workstation.

Comment: Exactly right. I didn't realize what an OVF file was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use vmware to open (Workstation->File->Open) the VM. I might prompt you to ask whether the VM is copied or moved, selected moved.

Comment: Uh, thanks but that sounds the same as what I described in my question.

Comment: @JonathanWoods The was right. I did not realized your screenshot was OVF file as well.